# Загрузка картинок на сервер с сервиса torg.mail.ru

Tags: файлы, php, загрузка, битрикс

Добрый день! Пишу парсер для сайта на битриксе. Задача загружать данные о товарах с сервиса torg.mail.ru, парсер работает, информацию с о товарах подтягивает. Одна проблема 1С Битрикс не работает с удалёнными файлами, т.е. нельзя в карточку товара в поле "Детальная картинка" или "Картинка для анонса" просто вставить путь к файлу лежащему на другом сервер. Поэтому надо грузить эти картинки куда-нибудь в /upload/produdct_img/.... вот как это сделать ума не приложу. Товаров может быть много 1000 или больше, у каждого товара от 1 до 5 картинок, т.е. картинок может быть несколько тысяч. Как организовать такую загрузку? Есть ли какой-ниубудь хитрый скрипт на php который бы получал на входе путь к файлу на другом сервере и путь куда его нужно подгрузить? Ничего дельного в интернет не нашёл все пишут про загрузку файлов на сервер из веб-формы. В общем нужна Ваша помощь.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К фрилансерам это не интересно. Решение я нашёл, не в рунете правда. Выглядит так:

```
            file_put_contents($NewFullPath, fopen($imagePath, 'r'));
```

Где $NewFullPath полный путь (включая имя) к месту куда засунуть новый файл, а $imagePath - путь к изображению который я получаю с torg.mail.ru. Эта функция отлично работает в цикле, сервер прекрасно справляется. Вот как-то так. )

Comment: Надо не забыть еще проверки добавить на права на запись файла и на существование удаленного файла